# Can I use AWS Glue to convert json data on S3 to columnar format and push it to Redshift?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I have data in nested JSON format on S3 which keeps on updating. I want the data to periodically push this data to Redshift cluster after the conversion. Can AWS Glue be helpful in configuring the periodic runs that converting the format to columnar and pushing it to Redshift?

Comment: yes it can - it is one of the options you have

Comment: Define a trigger and link it with the job you want to run. There are different time option to run your job such as periodic, on-demand, after another job. etc.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Glue ETL can run a Python script that transforms the data any way you want. Here's [an example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/simplify-querying-nested-json-with-the-aws-glue-relationalize-transform/) they put together where they flatten JSON via the `Relationalize` transform.